# Rsync --chownflag= flag is ignored

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to transfer local files to a remote web folder to get a site running using an admin user created for the scope.

My rsync command is as follows:

```
sudo rsync -Orv --chown=www-data:www-data index.html myuser@myip:/var/www/mysite/public_html
```

Files are transferred correctly, however the flag chown=www-data:www-data is ignored and as a such files ownership remains set the user that initiated the ssh connection, so in this case they will be myuser:myuser.

I tried also with the `--usermap=*:www-data --groupmap=*:www-data` alternative, receiving the `no matches found:--usermap=*:www-data` error message.

I couldn't find any log file where the rsync operations are recorded. I though initially this was in the SSH file, for which LogLevel has been increased to VERBOSE, but this didn't give me any additional hints.

And I couldn't find any possible explanation to the problem. The local rsync version is 3.1.2

Any idea on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rsync ... --chown=www-data:www-data index.html myuser@myip:/var/www/mysite/public_html
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

On the remote system that is receiving the files, you're logging in as "myuser". Assuming the remote system is a typical unix system, and "myuser" isn't "root", this remote process wouldn't have permission to change ownership on any file to "www-data".

If you want to create files owned by "www-data" on the remote system, the remote process has to run as the user "www-data" or else as "root" or some root equivalent.

Comment: the remote system is a Ubunti 16.04 LTS and myuser has been included into the sudo group, that's why I couldn't figure out the reason why permissions aren't changed. Is there any log file I can look at?

Comment: So apparently passing a -og I was able to retain the group. I'd say that this is mostly due to the g, which says "preserve the group". Can't understand why the -o didn't work though. And yes, the online manual is quite cryptic when it says "preserve", because to me that implies "preserving something from the original".